# Creating Kafka producer in .NET by passing in message

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, producer

I am wondering if anyone here in R&D has any experience with Kafka using .NET. The below code snippet is from a client and it is written in Java. It seems that the Kafka libraries for Java are much richer than those for .NET. What I am attempting to do is start up a Kafka producer on a remote server at the client site so that RTA states are delivered through the Kafka producer.

What I need to do is recreate the below code in .NET, especially the last line 'openInterfacesSubscriber.send()'. I am using a .NET package from Confluent. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:9092");
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "ept-oi-log");
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "1");
         props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
IntegerDeserializer.class);

props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
StringDeserializer.class); 

DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Integer, String> producer = new 
DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>( producerConfigs(props));

KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> openInterfacesSubscriber = new KafkaTemplate<> 
(producer); 

for (all in { "AGENTBYACCOUNTMEASURES", "AGENTBYROUTINGSERVICEMEASURES") {

String subRequest = String.format("   {\"userName\":\"%s\",\"password\":\"%s\",\"subscriptionRequestId\":\"5d09vjfgk\",\"request\":\"SUBSCRIBE\", \"measuresStream\":\"% s\",\"version\":\"3.4\"}", "MikeGrey@odl.lab",  "Avaya123", measureName); 

// THERE IS NO KAFKA SECURITY HERE: USERNAME/PWD ABOVE IS FOR THE subRequest
// STRING ONLY, ANYONE CAN CONNECT TO THIS KAKFA INSTANCE.

openInterfacesSubscriber.send("realtimesubscriptionrequest", 0, i++, subRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The .NET API is still being worked on, its also a bit tricky to host on windows (or so I found).

I have been using the experimental .net Kafka client and found it quite easy to "map" to the java source you posted:

- The configuration map just becomes a dictionary
- The serialization/deserialization setup can be done in code via parameters to the `Producer` constructor. You might need to change the encoding.
- `KafkaTemplate<>.send` maps to `Producer.ProduceAsync`

Bearing in mind that the client is still evolving, here's a version of your code that works for me with the noted nuget version:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{          
    // Client: .net core console app 2.0 / Confluent.Kafka nuget 1.0.0-experimental-2
    // Server: Kafka 1.0.0
    Dictionary<string, object> config = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "bootstrap.servers", "ept-oi-log" },
        { "group.id", "ept-oi-log" },
        { "enable.auto.commit", true },
        { "session.timeout.ms", 15000 },
        { "client.id", "1" },
    };

    Producer(config).Wait();
}

static async Task Producer(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> kafkaConfig)
{
    var kafkaTopic = "realtimesubscriptionrequest";
    using (var producer = new Producer<int, string>(kafkaConfig, new IntSerializer(), new StringSerializer(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)))
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var measureName in new[] { "AGENTBYACCOUNTMEASURES", "AGENTBYROUTINGSERVICEMEASURES" })
        {
            String subRequest = String.Format(@"   {{""userName"":""{0}"",""password"":""{1}"",""subscriptionRequestId"":""5d09vjfgk"",""request"":""SUBSCRIBE"", ""measuresStream"":""{2}"",""version"":""3.4""}}", 
                "ggghhhh@xxx.lab", "xxxxxxx", measureName);
            await producer.ProduceAsync(kafkaTopic, new Message<int, string>() { Key = i++, Value = subRequest });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not supposed to say thanks here, but thanks anyway Peter, I appreciate your help with this issue. I was thinking the ProduceAsync was the correct method to use but I definitely was not setting the parameter list up the same as you have it here. I have been on vacation since I posted this question and will not be back to work until April 23 where I am anxious to try your suggestion out. I will let you know if this works for me. Again thank you for you kind help.